# Are warnings important when using the package ensr?

Tags: r

I am using the package `ensr` for estimating the coefficients of a multinomial model. The code that I use is the following:

```
Net_elastic_m2 <- ensr(y = DV_HAR_model2, x =IV_HAR_model2 , family = "multinomial", type.multinomial = "grouped",  maxit=10^6)
```

When the results are ready I have the following warning:

```
There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Using the command `warnings()` I have the following 19 warning messages `1: In log(bigY) : NaNs produced` I am not sure if the results are robust in spite of the warnings.

I am thinking that the function does not find the optimal result, maybe I have to increase the number of iterations or not. Can someone try to explain me this warning?

Comment: What is the output of `warnings()`? Probably to do with how you're fitting the model. Might need data sample and/or better asked at CV.

Comment: @NelsonGon the output is `In log(bigY) : NaNs produced` I did not provide the data because is too big, and the time required to get the result is almost one hour.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert in models. This is likely a model issue. I suggest asking at Cross Validated or your advisor to verify that this model is the right one to fit.